# Can this integral be obtained in closed form?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling with the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{-a}^a\int_{0}^b \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2+1-2r\cos(\theta)}} dr dz d\theta
$$

,where $a,b>0$. I've tried to get a hint from Wolfram Alpha, but Wolfram Alpha could not evaluate this integral. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you derive this integral from something else, or was it given to you this way exactly?

Comment: In fact, I was trying to obtain potential energy by gravitational force due to finite cylinder, which is physics problem. But I thought solving the given integral is necessary, so I was struggling with it.

Comment: Using a CAS, the most inner integral does not make problem. For the next, it is long but it works. For the last one, it would probably be better to forget it.